# how to add a static route to external gateway(external IP)?

Tags: fedora, route

I am having an issue with setting up a static route in Fedora.

I need to route some traffic to an external gateway(105.101.67.70 - public IP address of a VPN router). Any request sent to 125.106.67.70 needs to be routed to VPN router gateway 105.101.67.70 and the router will connect it to a VPN network. Fedore server, VPN router and the VPN network are located in different locations and all connected through internet.

Tried following steps in command line:

```
route add -net 125.106.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 105.101.67.70 dev eth0
```

The result:

```
SIOCADDRT: No such process
```

Route info:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.250.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.250.241 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY is public IP address of VPN router.

Comment: There's a reason why obfuscating your IP addresses is a *really* bad idea.  Real IPs please.

Comment: YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY meant to be a confidential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This almost certainly means that you don't have a route for `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` (i.e. 105.101.67.70).

Given lack of detail, I am going to assume you don't have anything unusual going on.  Basically your route statement is never going to work given the addresses you have posted currently. To add a route the gateway must be on a network that is directly connected, and given your current route table, it means the gateway for that route must be an address on the network `192.168.250.0/24`.

To use a gateway your box must be able to directly send the packets to the gateway, on Ethernet, that means your computer must be able to successfully receive an ARP response for `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY`.  That can only really happen if `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` is on a subnet that is locally connected. By locally connected I mean there is no layer 3 devices between your box and `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY`.  If `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` is not local, then you are almost certainly trying to add a route on the wrong device, and you should be adding it on the router that is directly connected to `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY`.

Comment: yes, this is the issue i am trying to solve.

Comment: Thou you added some detail you haven't really added the correct details. What we need to understand is where is `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` in relation to the external interface of your router?  Is it directly connected?  Is it inside, where is it?

Comment: Thou you added some detail you haven't really added the correct details. What we need to understand is where is `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` in relation to the external interface of your router? Is it directly connected? Is it inside, where is it?  A network diagram would probably be the most helpful here.

Comment: thanks for comments. i think i understood the limitation. YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY is outside of the network, i will move put it in the same network and try. thanks.